# How to exit If before hit Then and End If statement?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need a way to end If before "Then"

```
For i = 0 To Main.[B10000].End(xlUp).Row - 4

    POD = Trim(Main.Range("B5").Offset(i, 0))
    If POD <> "" Then

        L2 = "https:/AAAAA" & POD

        P.Open "Get", L2
        P.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
        P.send
        P.waitForResponse

        D.body.innerHTML = P.responseText

        For Each R In D.getElementsByClassName("col-md-7")
            If InStr(1, R.innerText, "pod is not found on floor") <> 0 Then
                Main.Range("B5").Offset(i, 1) = "Offline"

                **'I need end here if = Offline**

            Else
                Main.Range("B5").Offset(i, 1) = "Online"
            End If
        Next R
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'end'? At the moment, you say you want to finish the `If`, in which case you can nest another `If … Then` statement. Or do you want to `Exit For` the inner loop? Or do you need a new construct such as `Do While` or `Do Until`? At the moment, readers are unclear as to what you mean.

Comment: If "offline" I need exit the "For R" loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AJD mentioned, you can exit for after setting B5 cell's value to "offline"

```
For i = 0 To Main.[B10000].End(xlUp).Row - 4

POD = Trim(Main.Range("B5").Offset(i, 0))
If POD <> "" Then

    L2 = "https:/AAAAA" & POD

    P.Open "Get", L2
    P.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
    P.send
    P.waitForResponse

    D.body.innerHTML = P.responseText

    For Each R In D.getElementsByClassName("col-md-7")
        If InStr(1, R.innerText, "pod is not found on floor") <> 0 Then
            Main.Range("B5").Offset(i, 1) = "Offline"
            Exit For
        Else
            Main.Range("B5").Offset(i, 1) = "Online"
        End If
    Next R
End If
```

Next i

Comment: I swear that I tried this before, but anyway worked great!